# Is it possible to add <script> tag into flutter project?

Tags: javascript, flutter

I am building a radio mobile app using Flutter and need to add some JavaScript embed codes provided by the Radio Management software. The script code is as follows

Does anyone know how I could add this to the project?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13v_BwZcCLk

Comment: have you found any help?